# How to interpolate (ordinary kriging) large files with QGIS processing

Tags: qgis, saga, qgis-processing, kriging

I'm using the Saga ordinary kriging tool as apart of different processing models. The biggest issue I have is the very slow performance. My point shape files have mostly more than 200.00 points (some are >500.00). My workaround is to interpolate the points in SAGA and export them back into QGIS. That is really annoying because I have to switch between the programs. Is there another chance to speed up the performance in QGIS? Or is there another faster tool I could use?

Comment: Running the processing tool outside QGIS in a standalone script _should_ increase performance but I guess you would still have to add the result back into QGIS.